# Javascript or JQuery Function to get All TimeZones to Display in DOJO Combobox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

Is there any default or custom function to display all timezones combo box in DOJO using ItemFileReadStore?

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no function in JS to get all the time zones. Only thing you get is time zone offset bye following code.

```
var date = new Date(),
    zoneOffset = date.getTimezoneOffset();
```

And in dojo you can get name of timezone

```
require(["dojo/date"], function(date){
  var myDate = (2000, 5, 16);
  date.getTimezoneName(myDate);
 });
```

I have used in past http://momentjs.com/timezone/data/ JS but it is currently under development again.

Comment: This i have googled,but my requirement is to get all timezones

Comment: you cannot get it. you can download data from google and you can save into static JSON.